# Fixed effect on overlap of factors

Tags: r, statistics, lm, model.matrix

I'm trying to generate a model.matrix that puts dummy variables for a categorical variable if it exists in either of a pair of factors. Here is an example:

```
group1 <- factor(c("A","A","A","A","B",
                   "B","B","C","C","D"),
                 levels=c("A","B","C","D","E"))

group2 <- factor(c("B","C","D","E","C",
                   "D","E","D","E","E"),
                 levels=levels(group1))

set.seed(8)
val <- rnorm(10,1,.25)
control1 <- rnorm(10,2,.5)

df <- data.frame(group1,
                 group2,
                 val,
                 control1)
```

This results in 10 rows for the (5*(5-1)/2) pairs of (A,B,C,D,E):

```
df
   group1 group2       val control1
1       A      B 0.9788535 1.620103
2       A      C 1.2101000 2.146025
3       A      D 0.8841293 2.210699
4       A      E 0.8622912 1.352755
5       B      C 1.1840101 2.034643
6       B      D 0.9730296 1.593481
7       B      E 0.9574277 2.755427
8       C      D 0.7279171 1.864196
9       C      E 0.2472371 2.779127
10      D      E 0.8517064 1.881325
```

I want to control for a fixed effect in a linear model when a particular level is in either group1 or group2. I can construct a model matrix for this:

```
tmp1 <- model.matrix(~ 0+group1,df)
tmp2 <- model.matrix(~ 0+group2,df)

tmp3 <- (tmp1|tmp2)*1

tmp3
   group1A group1B group1C group1D group1E
1        1       1       0       0       0
2        1       0       1       0       0
3        1       0       0       1       0
4        1       0       0       0       1
5        0       1       1       0       0
6        0       1       0       1       0
7        0       1       0       0       1
8        0       0       1       1       0
9        0       0       1       0       1
10       0       0       0       1       1
```

A few questions:

Doing it this way does not leave me a lot of options in terms of other covariates. How can I construct such a dummy variable as represented by the model matrix `tmp3` and then use it in a call to `lm` with other covariates such as `control1`?

The idea is that there is a fixed effect on whether an individual (A,B,C,D,E) is in either group1 or group2. This seems like a reasonable assumption, but I haven't found any references. Am I missing something obvious or does this have a common name in statistics?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: try `+(Reduce('|',lapply(df[1:2], function(x) model.matrix(~0+x))))`

Comment: That doesn't work in the call to lm: lm(val~0+(Reduce('|',lapply(df[1:2], function(x) model.matrix(~0+x)))), data=df) returns in error since that term is a matrix.

Comment: How about wrapping with `as.data.frame`

Comment: That with multiplying the `Reduce` by 1 to switch to numeric makes the estimation work. Now I'm realizing the coefficients aren't what I thought they would be. I'm going to leave it open to focus on the second part of my question. Thanks!

Comment: I guess your second question is more statistical rather than programming question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if `model.matrix` does provide any options from this, but at least in your example you can reconstruct the matrix you are after without too much effort.

```
model_mat <- data.frame(tmp3[,-1], val = df$val, control1 = df$control1)
lm(val ~ ., data = model_mat)
```

You need to remove one of the dummies, I have removed A but you can of course pick any of the others as reference category.

Comment: That gets the job done. Moving the second part to cross validated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using akrun's idea:

```
group1 <- factor(c("A","A","A","A","B",
                   "B","B","C","C","D"),
                 levels=c("A","B","C","D","E"))

group2 <- factor(c("B","C","D","E","C",
                   "D","E","D","E","E"),
                 levels=levels(group1))

set.seed(8)
val <- rnorm(10,1,.25)
control1 <- rnorm(10,2,.5)

df <- data.frame(group1,
                 group2,
                 val,
                 control1)

tmpval <- as.data.frame(Reduce('|',lapply(df[1:2], function(group) model.matrix(~0+group)))*1)

indf <- cbind(df,tmpval)

mod1 <- lm(val ~ 0+groupA+groupB+groupC+groupD+groupE,
           indf)

summary(mod1)
```